# Doxygen - Backslashes in comment

Tags: doxygen, clion

I want to add a Windows path that contains backslashes to a doxygen comment like this:

```
/**
 *
 * Returns common AppData directory, usually C:\ProgramData\
 *
 */
```

I tried it with two backslashes but CLion always displays it as new section.  Is this a problem with CLion or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I very much doubt the IDE is the problem... Doxygen is apart from the IDE. Could you please provide your version with two backslashes? According to [this](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdbackslash), it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen will see the `\ProgramData` as a possible command and leave it out. Solutions for this are either:

- escaping the backslash so: `C:\\ProgramData\\`
- using backticks, this will also change the font (something I would prefer to signal that it is a computer directory:

  ```
  `C:\ProgramData\`
  ```